# Docker RUN PWD is at root inside windows instead of the current working directory

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile

For some odd reason my present working directory is /. It should be the current directory of the dockerfile, but it is not. Anyone seen this before? I am on windows using PowerShell and Cmder both and getting the same results.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2

#WORKDIR /bin
RUN pwd
RUN ls -la

#COPY . app/

RUN dotnet --version
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app/simple-dotnet-api.dll"]
```

Output:

```
λ docker build --no-cache -t simpledotnetapi .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  252.4kB
Step 1/6 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2
 ---> 08663b8eaa01
Step 2/6 : RUN ls -la
 ---> Running in ac2e849a757e
total 72
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 13 16:17 .
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 13 16:17 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    0 Jun 13 16:17 .dockerenv
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 11 00:30 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Mar 28 09:12 boot
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  340 Jun 13 16:17 dev
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 13 16:17 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Mar 28 09:12 home
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 10 00:00 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun 10 00:00 lib64
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun 10 00:00 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun 10 00:00 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun 10 00:00 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 144 root root    0 Jun 13 16:17 proc
drwx------   1 root root 4096 Jun 11 08:07 root
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Jun 10 00:00 run
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 11 00:30 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun 10 00:00 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 Jun 13 15:46 sys
drwxrwxrwt   1 root root 4096 Jun 11 00:30 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 10 00:00 usr
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 10 00:00 var
Removing intermediate container ac2e849a757e
 ---> 50062f08e279
Step 3/6 : RUN pwd
 ---> Running in f79599959874
/
Removing intermediate container f79599959874
 ---> 8af3de2e5e58
Step 4/6 : COPY . app/
 ---> 32d77a7cf452
Step 5/6 : RUN dotnet --version
 ---> Running in f1f83285eff2
2.2.300
Removing intermediate container f1f83285eff2
 ---> f0bb4891b002
Step 6/6 : ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app/simple-dotnet-api.dll"]
 ---> Running in 3978dee3fdcf
Removing intermediate container 3978dee3fdcf
 ---> af95f20afbbe
Successfully built af95f20afbbe
Successfully tagged simpledotnetapi:latest
```

Comment: i don't understand your question. The ```ls -la``` show the files inside the container not the files on the Host, if you need to use some files on you computer you can: mount the folder on the container with the ```-v``` flag when you run the container, use the docker-compose and mount the folder, or you can use ```COPY``` command inside the Dockerfile

Comment: Gianmarco, thanks for the response. I was trying to copy the files on the host which reside in a child folder into the docker image but it is telling me the child folder does not exist, that led me to trying to using pwd and ls -al to try and see why my COPY command would not work with a child directory. Here is my copy command: COPY bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/publish/* app/. The result is "no source files were specified".

Comment: Try `COPY ./bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/publish/* app/`

Comment: I didn't have any luck with that Chetan, it complains that no source files were found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `RUN pwd` inside a Dockerfile will print the current working directory of the image and not the directory where the Dockerfile is located.

When running [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#extended-description) you pass in a build context. In your case where you are using `docker build --no-cache -t simpledotnetapi .` the `.` (current directory) is the context for the build. A `COPY /source /destination` will look for `source` in the root of the build context and try to copy it to `/destination` inside the container.

Using an analogy, running `docker build` is similar to using a remote shell to run a series of instructions on a remote machine, but with a shared directory being the build context.